# How to get source host from Azure Application Gateway queries

Tags: azure, url, azure-application-gateway

I am using that query to get detailed information about incomming requests since I am looking for the source address of hosts that sends queries:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where Category == "ApplicationGatewayAccessLog"
| where host_s == "xxxxx.com"
| where httpStatus_d == "502"
| sort by TimeGenerated
```

Is it possible, by modyfing above one, or by adding something to it to know source URL / IP address that sends queries.
Issue here is that there are too many req going through Azure Application gateway and Tomcat server on AKS cluster cannot deal with that amount - and gives 502 is application's pods.
I am looking for IP or URL address that those req are comming from (through App Gateway).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get the Incoming request of Application gateway you can make us of below queries.

```c
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceType == "APPLICATIONGATEWAYS" and OperationName == "ApplicationGatewayAccess"
| summarize AggregatedValue = count() by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h), _ResourceId, clientIP_s
```

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/0AFkASu.png)]

> `clientIp` IP of the immediate client of Application Gateway. If
> another proxy fronts your application gateway, this displays the IP of
> that fronting proxy.

To check the logs, you can make use of below queries.

```c
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceType == "APPLICATIONGATEWAYS" and OperationName == "ApplicationGatewayAccess"
| project TimeGenerated, ResourceId, httpStatus_d, clientIP_s, requestUri_s
```

[image]

To Filter Top 10 `client Ip`:

```c
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceType == "APPLICATIONGATEWAYS" and OperationName == "ApplicationGatewayAccess"
| summarize AggregatedValue = count() by clientIP_s
| top 10 by AggregatedValue
```

Here is the list of all Application gateway queries you can use [Application Gateway - Kusto Queries](https://kustoqueries.com/Networking/Application-Gateway/Application-Gateway.pdf)

Enable Diagnostics settings of Application Gateway:

[image]

***Reference***:

[Diagnostic logs - Azure Application Gateway | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-diagnostics#access-log)

[Examine WAF logs using Azure Log Analytics - Azure Application Gateway | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/log-analytics#matchedblocked-requests-by-ip)